# TSQL: Inserting missing records into table

Tags: t-sql

I am stuck at this T-SQL query.
I have table below

```
 Age   SectioName  Cost 
 ---------------------
 1      Section1    100
 2      Section1    200
 1      Section2    500
 3      Section2    100
 4      Section2    200
```

Lets say for each section I can have maximum 5 Age. In above table there are some missing Ages. How do I insert missing Ages for each section. (Possibly without using cursor). The cost would be zero for missing Ages

So after the insertion the table should look like

```
 Age SectioName  Cost 
 ---------------------
  1    Section1    100
  2    Section1    200
  3    Section1    0
  4    Section1    0
  5    Section1    0
  1    Section2    500  
  2    Section2    0
  3    Section2    100
  4    Section2    200
  5    Section2    0
```

**EDIT1**
I should have been more clear with my question.  The maximum age is dynamic value. It could be 5,6,10 or someother value but it will be always less than 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it

```
;WITH tally AS
    (
            SELECT 1 AS r
            UNION ALL
            SELECT r + 1 AS r
            FROM  tally
            WHERE r < 5 -- this value could be dynamic now
    )
select n.r, t.SectionName, 0 as Cost
from (select distinct SectionName from TempFormsSectionValues) t
cross join
(select ta.r FROM tally ta) n
where not exists
  (select * from TempFormsSectionValues where YearsAgo = n.r and SectionName = t.SectionName)
order by t.SectionName, n.r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to select missing value:

```
select n.num, t.SectioName, 0 as Cost
from (select distinct SectioName from table1) t
cross join
(select 1 as num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5) n
where not exists
  (select * from table1 where table1.age = n.num and table1.SectioName = t.SectioName)
```

It creates a Cartesian product of sections and numbers 1 to 5 and then selects those that doesn't exist yet. You can then use this query for the source of `insert into` your table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/564f9/21) (it has `order by` added to check the results easier but it's not necessary for inserting).

Comment: When you say the value is dynamic, is it the same for all sections? Can you still use the query above?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to generate missing rows

```
SELECT t1.Age,t1.Section,ISNULL(t2.Cost,0) as Cost
FROM
(
SELECT 1 as Age,'Section1' as Section,0 as Cost
UNION
SELECT 2,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 3,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 4,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 5,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 1,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 2,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 3,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 4,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 5,'Section2',0
  ) as t1

 LEFT JOIN test t2
 ON t1.Age=t2.Age AND t1.Section=t2.Section
 ORDER BY Section,Age
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9035/9)

You can utilize above result set for inserting missing rows by using **EXCEPT** operator to exclude already existing rows in table -

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT t1.Age,t1.Section,ISNULL(t2.Cost,0) as Cost
FROM
(
SELECT 1 as Age,'Section1' as Section,0 as Cost
UNION
SELECT 2,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 3,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 4,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 5,'Section1',0
UNION
SELECT 1,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 2,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 3,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 4,'Section2',0
UNION
SELECT 5,'Section2',0
  ) as t1

 LEFT JOIN test t2
 ON t1.Age=t2.Age AND t1.Section=t2.Section

EXCEPT 

SELECT Age,Section,Cost
FROM test

SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY Section,Age
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9035/11